# Does Hashem have authority over the decisions of the Rabbis?

Tags: talmud-gemara, rabbis, gehinnom

Shalom Rabbi,

I am seeking assistance with a question that arose during my Torah study.

In this Gemara, a Torah scholar named Aher spoke to a child with a stutter. The man Aher thought the child insulted him. The pesuk makes a statement in which G-d is a witness to the child’s statement.

My question relates to the fact that men in the Heavenly Academy did not ask their Creator for His opinion. What function does G-d have in His heavenly realm? Does the Talmud consider Hashem’s Torah secondary to their Oral Law Torah as in [Eruvin 21b:8][1]?

Chagigah 15b:2-3

The Gemara relates: That child had a stutter, so it sounded as though he were saying to him: Vele’elisha, i.e., and to Elisha, God says. This made Elisha think the child was deliberately insulting him. Some say Aḥer had a knife, and he tore the child apart and sent him to the thirteen synagogues. And others say that Aḥer merely said: Had I a knife, I would have torn him apart.

The Gemara relates: When Aḥer passed away, the Heavenly Court declared that he should not be judged, nor brought into the World-to-Come. He should not be judged in a manner befitting his deeds, because he occupied himself with Torah, whose merit protects him. And he should not be brought into the World-to-Come because he sinned. Rabbi Meir said: It is better that he be judged properly and be brought into the World-to-Come. When I die I will request this of Heaven, and I will cause smoke to rise up from his grave, as a sign that he is being sentenced in Gehenna. The Gemara relates: When Rabbi Meir passed away, smoke rose up from the grave of Aḥer, implying that Rabbi Meir’s wish was granted.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

B”H

Gabriel Schecter

[1]: https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.21b.8?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en#:~:text=My%20son%2C%20be%20careful%20to,a%20snake%20shall%20bite%20him%E2%80%9D%20(

Comment: Hi welcome to Mi Yodeya. Perhaps the question needs a little editing as it's not completely clear what you are asking? Do note that Aher is Elisha Ben Avuya, he was one of the four that went into the Pardes, and he came back a heretic. Therefore, the incident in the Heavenly Court not wanting to admit him pertains to that, and not the incident with the child. That might clear up the question? See https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/81604.2?lang=bi&p2=Chagigah.15a&lang2=bi

Comment: Check out Bava Metzia 59b